# Ajax post request return json data not updating

Tags: ajax, json

I am really new to Javascript, Ajax and JSON. I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetBase64Image","Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data.imagefilename);
                displayImage(data);
            }
        })
    },5000));
```

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetBase64Image()
    {
        if (ImageIndex==ImageData.Length) ImageIndex=0;
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(ImageFileNames[ImageIndex]);
        return Json(new { base64image =  ImageData[ImageIndex++], imagefilename=fname }
            , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }   
}
```

I do see the GetBase64Image is being called every 5 seconds but the alert only displays the value from first call to the method. What am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not sending any parameters in the AJAX call. What's the purpose of the `contentType` option without parameters? Note that jQuery always sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`.

Comment: You have a typo: `datatype:` should be `dataType:`.

Comment: What language is the server code? Are you sure it preserves `ImageIndex` across different calls? If it's not a session variable, I'd expect it to be reset on each call.